# Navigation Menu: css vertical centering

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a navigation menu that is evenly spaced regardless if the menu item is 1 line or 2 lines of text.  I have this working with 1 line of text but the vertical spacing of the text is off if an item hits more than one line.

My code that I have so far is below.  Any help would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wnfUC/

***Style:***

```
       #pageNavigation {
        background-image: url('../Images/TIBC_Base/nav-bg.png');
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        margin:5px 0;
        padding:5px 15px 5px;
        min-height:125px;
}
    #pageNavigation_bottom
    {
        clear:both;
        background-image: url('../Images/TIBC_Base/nav-bg_bottom.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin:-5px 0 0 -1px;
        min-height:8px;
    }
    #pageNavigation .navContent{ width:240px; margin:0 -10px; }
    #pageNavigation ul { list-style-type: none; margin:0; padding:0; }
    #pageNavigation ul li { display: block; height:57px; border-top:0px #E1E1E1 solid; border-bottom:1px #E1E1E1 solid; text-align:center; overflow:hidden; }
    #pageNavigation a  {
        color:#485963;
        font-size:16px;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-shadow: 0px -1px #EEEEEE;
        display:block;
        height:57px;    
    }
    #pageNavigation a:hover
    {
        background: #FAE2AD;
        color: #485963;
    }
    #pageNavigation a.NavigationSelected
    {
        color:#F9F9F9;
        background: #A5B5BE;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px #485963;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
```

***HTML***

```
    <div id="pageNavigation">
<ul class="navContent">
<li><a href="/Services">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="/Services/Analysis">Analysis</a></li>
<li><a href="/Services/Strategic-Planning">Strategic Planning</a></li>
<li><a href="/Services/International-Market-and-Competitor-Research">International Market and Competitor Research</a></li>
<li><a href="/Services/Budgeting-and-Forecasting">Budgeting and Forecasting</a></li>
<li><a href="/Services/International-Cultural-Liaison" class="NavigationSelected">International Cultural Liaison</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You should create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) recreating this issue.

Comment: Thanks - I just created the fiddle demo.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS table layout (not HTML table element, eh!) to achieve this: http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/ZszJm/

`ul` is displayed with the same algorithm as a table, links with the same algorithm than cells and here `li` are displayed as rows as it's vertical. And then you can play with `vertical-align` as much as you want :) (in your case `middle` value)
You can add `table-layout: fixed` to `ul` and then browsers will use the *other* algorithm for displaying tables, the one that doesn't try to adapt widths and heights of cells to their content but will stick to what CSS rules say.

Compatibility: IE8 and above. It won't be centered in IE7 and 6, not a big deal.

EDIT: with this method, you don't need to know in advance which items are longer than others. Browsers will figure that.

Answer (score 0):

Vertical alignment of text is generally accomplished using `line-height`: http://jsfiddle.net/Shmiddty/wnfUC/1/

```
#pageNavigation a  {
    ...
    height:57px;  
    line-height:57px;        
}
#pageNavigation a.two-line{
    line-height:20px;
    padding-top:10px;    
}
```

Note that I added the class `two-line` to the anchor element that spanned two lines.

Comment: Then you must know in advance which items occupy 2 lines and which ones do not. In a multilingual website for example, it'll be different from a language to another...

Comment: @FelipeAls correct, but in the case of required backwards compatibility in a non-multilingual environment, this is an alternate option.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this method:  http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/

There are also some other methods you could use, but they require extra HTML markup, which this one does not.